# Python argv taking wild card path

Tags: python, python-2.7, glob

I run my script with `doc1/*.png` as first argument, but it gets converted to `doc1/image1.png`.

How can I let Python see the exact argument?

```
img_list = []
print sys.argv[1]
x = sys.argv[1]
img_list = [img for img in glob.glob(x)]
```

Comment: That's done at the shell level.

Comment: try quoting on Linux: `"doc1/*.png"`

Comment: If the arg is wrapped with single quotes like that on the command line then the shell shouldn't expand it. What shell are you using?

Comment: ubuntu shell, is it same in windows ?

Comment: When you say "ubuntu shell", I assume you mean Bash, because that's the standard shell on Ubuntu and many other Linux distros, especially those in the Debian family.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On most linux shells (`bash`, `sh`, `fish`,...), the asterisk is handled by the shell. The fact that the `*` is converted to a list of files **is already done at the shell level**.

If you write:

```
python file.py doc/*.png
```

The **shell itself** will translate `doc/*.png` into `"doc/1.png" "doc/2.png"` (so a list of `.png` files it finds in the `doc` directory.

You should **use quotes to pass the asterisk**, like:

```
python file.py 'doc/*.png'
```

The standard Windows shell does *not* do wildcards for file names.

Comment: that's not true on windows where you have the exact opposite problem and you have to use `glob.glob`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: thanks. I don't use Windows you see :) I prefer a [shell from the 90s](https://fishshell.com/) :).

Answer (score 3):

As @Jean-François Fabre sais, it is possible to use wildcards on windows using glob module.

```
import glob
paths = glob.glob('C:\path\with\wildcard.*')
```